# Android Experiments drain battery

Tags: usb, battery, charging, usb-debugging

While I am experimenting with Android I found it annoying that the device even if is plugged in on the PC using a USB is discharging.

THe problem is that I am performing some intensive experiments and are consuming a lot of power. (processing, screen, internet)

I know that every USB port or USB HUB port offers 500mA power in each connected Device and PowerTutor shows that the device consumes near 800-900mA thus it drains the battery.

Can you please suggest me some options?

For example:

Are there any USB Hubs offering 1A as output?
Can I use a dual usb cable instead? The same usb cables used to power hard drives?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Wireless ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=siir.es.adbWireless) (note: root required) to connect over wifi and then you can plug in your device to the power socket.

Comment: That link to Wireless ADB is broken.

Comment: hm - it's working for me - it may be country specific.  Regardless, there seem to be multiple 'wireless adb' apps around https://play.google.com/store/search?q=wireless+adb&c=apps